# How to ensure strict ordering of events across managed/unmanaged boundaries

Tags: c#, c++

I have C# code which generates timestamped events.  They also get a sequence number, so they can be strictly ordered (even across threads).  Something along these lines:

```
private static int NextInSequence = 0;
private int Sequence;
private DateTime TimeStamp;
private void CaptureState()
{
    this.TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    this.Sequence = Interlocked.Increment(ref NextInSequence);
}
```

Ideally, only timestamp would be required to put them in the correct order, but it can generate dozens of events within the resolution of a single increment of DateTime.UtcNow.  So Sequence is used for ordering when timestamps are equal.

None of that is a problem until I introduced C++ into the mix.  I ported the code to C++, and that code is PInvoked from the C# code, so events from the two get intermingled.  They calculate timestamps the same way, but I discovered I have an issue when the C++ code generates events with the same timestamp as the C# code.  All the C++ stuff is in order, and the C# is also in order, but their interactions are out of order.

So if events occur in this actual order on a thread:

```
Managed event => Unmanaged event => Unmanaged event => Managed event
```

it might end up sorted like this:

```
Managed event => Managed event => Unmanaged event => Unmanaged event
```

The order of interaction between threads doesn't matter so much as making sure everything that happens on one thread stays in the same order it was created.

I thought if I use a higher resolution timestamp, so each event gets a unique timestamp, I'd be in business.  So the next attempt uses QueryPerformanceCounter, something like this (excluding error checking and such):

```
static double tickFrequency = 10000000.0 / System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency;
static long UtcToPCDiff = CalcUtcDiff();
private static CalcUtcDiff()
{
    return DateTime.Utc.ToBinary() - (long)(Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() * tickFrequency);
}
public static GetUtcNow()
{
    return DateTime.FromBinary(UtcToPCDiff + (long)(Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() * tickFrequency));
}
```

That works in limited testing.  All the events come out in order, with relative timestamps accurate to full DateTime precision.  But then I read many comments about how unreliable QueryPerformanceCounter is.  And I realized that my timestamps will be completely inaccurate if, for example, the PC goes to sleep and then resumes, or the CPU changes frequency, etc.

Things I've considered and dismissed:

- I could pass the C# "NextInSequence" by ref to the C++ code and let it use that variable.  But that relies on the address of the static variable never changing.  Which may be true now, but no guarantee it will remain that way in the future.
- I could use Marshal to create a pointer to unmanaged memory, I know that will stay put, but then I can't call Interlocked.Increment on the memory pointed to by an IntPtr without some reflection shenanigans.
- I could pin an array of 1 int, but long term pinning can make life difficult for the garbage collector (although, ignoring the GC problem, that's probably the cleanest solution).
- I could make callbacks from the C++ to the C# code to ask for the next sequence.  But that would involve a quite significant performance hit.
- I could call GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime, which looks like it does exactly what I need.  But that function doesn't exist before Windows 8, and this has to work with Windows XP.

Sequence can be defined however I like, but Timestamp has to be at least close to UtcNow.

Anyone have any better ideas of how to order events?

Comment: I'm afraid that there's nothing much better than simple int increments in these scenarios, given the `DateTime` precision and `StopWatch` being more of a performance measurement utility. I just wonder whether you tried to measure performance of the callbacks from C++? I would expect the performance of `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `DateTime.UtcNow` combined with `Interlocked.Increment` on static field with heavy contention to be way worse than that.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered there's also another reason not to make callbacks to C#.  It could be running inside an application that blows up if you initialize .NET on the main thread (written before .NET existed).  Have to do a lot of work to make sure any callbacks happen on a safe thread.